# ASP.NET MVC 3: force user to specific page if info missing, similar to forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I'm working on the admin application for another application. Within the application are several organizations.  Admins can have administrative rights to one or more organizations.

I'd like to force users to pick a "current organization" to work with, right after login.  I would further like to force users back to that page if they browse straight to an inner page without that information being set, just as happens with login pages and forms authentication.

I would want to redirect back to the requested page after submit if the user was in fact forced back to the "select current organization" page, just as happens with forms authentication.

I'm thinking that this can probably be done fairly simply with action filters, but right at this point in time I'm blanking on how.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a custom Base Controller class.

Try putting the logic in these:

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext);
protected virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext);
```

Here is some more info...

```
// Use these to get current url info
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl

// use this to get current route info
filterContext.RouteData

// use this to redirect
filterContext.Result
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is it possible to extract the intended URL from the filter context parameter?  Will I have to modify the filter context before redirecting my user?

Comment: In MVC3 you can do this as a global ActionFilterAttribute which so you don't have to worry about Controller inheritance.